# Getting result of Groovy script into a GSP

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

I have a script that takes a bunch of XML info and outputs it in the following format:

```
==================
Package: code: VCOM_NIGHTOWL
==================
        ==================
        Quota Code Balance: code: NO_100G
        ==================
                id: _aiZVYKGuEeqHJ4kr1alp8Q
                initialAmount: 107374182400
                amount: 107374182400
                reservedAmount: 0
                startDate: 2020-05-29T15:15:00.000+02:00
                expirationDate: 2020-06-29T15:15:00.000+02:00
                rolloverPeriodAmount: 1
                rolloverPeriodUnits: Month
                rolloverExpirationDate: 2020-07-29T15:15:00.000+02:00
                rolloverTemplateName: NightOwl_Rollover
        ==================
        Quota Code Balance: code: NightOwl_Rollover
        ==================
                id: _aibxoKGuEeqHJ4kr1alp8Q
                initialAmount: 107374182400
                amount: 107374104877
                reservedAmount: 0
                startDate: 2020-05-29T15:15:00.000+02:00
                expirationDate: 2020-06-29T15:15:00.000+02:00
==================
Package: code: VCOM_BBC_DATA_ABT
==================
        ==================
        Quota Code Balance: code: DATA-100GB
        ==================
                id: _6DakwKGxEeqHJ4kr1alp8Q
                initialAmount: 107374182400
                amount: 107374182400
                reservedAmount: 125829120
                startDate: 2020-05-29T15:40:00.000+02:00
                expirationDate: 2020-06-29T15:40:00.000+02:00
                rolloverPeriodAmount: 1
                rolloverPeriodUnits: Month
                rolloverExpirationDate: 2020-07-29T15:40:00.000+02:00
                rolloverTemplateName: Rollover
        ==================
        Quota Code Balance: code: Rollover
        ==================
                id: _7m7EMIoeEeqfasqHpqlxMw
                initialAmount: 11181322002
                amount: 9394601779
                reservedAmount: 0
                startDate: 2020-04-29T15:40:00.000+02:00
                expirationDate: 2020-05-29T15:40:00.000+02:00
```

I want to render the whole lot in a Grails GSP.

I have tried to work out how I can run the script directly within the controller but I can't seem to figure it out.

This is the script code:

```
import groovy.json.*
import groovy.xml.*
import groovy.util.*
import java.time.*
import java.text.*
import groovy.transform.ToString 

def cps_post = new XmlSlurper().parse(new File("F:/SFTP Updates/Groovy/balance.xml"))
            def cpsPost = cps_post.Body.GetSubscriberResponse.subscriber

    
    def a = cpsPost.balance.code.size()
            println a

            def b = cpsPost.balance.quota.credit.size()
            println b
    
            def c = cpsPost.balance.quota.code.size()
            println c

            def d = cpsPost.balance.quota.size()
            println c
   
   
                for (int i = 0; i <= a; i++){
    
            cpsPost.balance[i].code.each { codetag ->
            println "=================="
            println "Package: ${codetag.name()}: ${codetag.text()}"
            println "=================="
    
            cpsPost.balance[i].quota.code.each { quotatag ->
            println "   =================="
            println "   Quota Code Balance: ${quotatag.name()}: ${quotatag.text()}"
            println "   =================="



    
    cpsPost.balance[i].quota.credit.each { credit ->
    credit.children().each { tag3 ->
    println "       ${tag3.name()}: ${tag3.text()}"
    
    
   }}
    }}}
    ].execute().text
```

I have also tried to run the script using a "process" cmd and then render the output ie:

```
def cpsBilling(){
    def process = "groovysh.bat F:/SFTP Updates/Groovy/cpsBilling.groovy".execute()
    render "Output: " + process.text          
}
```

This only renders the "Output" string and no process.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as it's driving me bananas.

Thanks

Comment: You should quote the path...

Answer (score 0):

In case it’s of use to anyone, I used a scriptlet in the GSP. It’s probably not the ideal solution but it works for what I need.